# HAProxy roundrobin rds via dns

Tags: amazon-web-services, haproxy

I am successfully setting up HAProxy in ubuntu 14 with this simple configuration

```
listen rds-cluster
    bind 10.0.0.204:3306
    mode tcp
    option mysql-check user ha_check
    balance roundrobin
    server mysql-1 ha1.xxxxxxx.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306 check weight 1 fall 2 fastinter 1000
    server mysql-2 ha2.xxxxxxx.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306 check weight 1 fall 2 fastinter 1000
```

Just in case of recreating the instance giving dynamic ip addresses, Is it possible to bind it using DNS that is pointing behind on a elastic ip address? even so it needed a private address. So I assume a setup like:

```
listen rds-cluster
    bind haproxy.dns.com.au
    option mysql-check user ha_check
    balance roundrobin
    server mysql-1 ha1.xxxxxxx.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306 check weight 1 fall 2 fastinter 1000
    server mysql-2 ha2.xxxxxxx.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306 check weight 1 fall 2 fastinter 1000
```

but when verifying using a command `mysql -h haproxy.dns.com.au -p'' -e "show variables like 'server_id'"` it is not responding. I understand what I am doing  is wrong. Can anyone guide me the setup I want to achieve. Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you need to specify an IP? If you can bind listen on all interfaces just use `bind :3306`

Comment: @Paulpro I get your point but when binding it only on the port `bind :3306 or bind *:3306` , I am getting `Starting proxy rds-cluster: cannot bind socket` ,